# in a cpu emulator is assembly required to call a external function

Tags: c, emulation, virtualization, cpu-registers

in a cpu emulator is assembly required to call a external function and store there return code or is it possible to do that from within the language the emulator is coded in, for example, in gnu gas 64 bit assembly:

```
        .file   "hello_world.c"
        .text
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "hello world"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
        call    puts@PLT
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

could one call puts via, say

```
rax = puts(/* register arguments 1 to 6 in order, plus stack arguments if any */);
```

in C, or would one be required to EXPLICITLY call puts via assembly via say calling a function, that contains inline asm, that takes viardic arguments, with the contents of each virtual cpu register, then in assembly copy those into the host registers themselves, call the desired function, then copy the host registers back into the virtual registers then return

Comment: Unclear, and off-topic since too broad. You need to read more about [Operating Systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Be sure to understand well the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) relevant for your (emulated) system. Study existing [x86 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)s

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch is that better?

Comment: Not really. You need to spend hours in reading the ABI relevant for your system. Once you have read them, you could ask a better (and more focused) question, which would probably cite some of that ABI. Actually, once you have studied your ABI, you'll have the answer to your question. You might also need to understand what [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)s exist on your (emulated) system

Comment: does that apply for the archetecture the cpu is emulating or does that apply to the host the emulator is running on, for example if i want to be able to run it on ARM and X86 would i need to know how functions are called for BOTH ARM and X86, or can i just forawd them through C, or would i need to reimpliment the entire libc implimentation in my cpu machine code then somehow externally call the hosts hardware to preform the required tasks such as writing to the screen or accessing the sound card ect

Comment: A given architecture (e.g. x86-64) can have (and usually does have) *several* ABIs. You need to choose one and read its specification. Of course, the usual ARM ABI (for Linux) is different than the x86-64 ABI (for Linux)

Comment: BTW a CPU emulator don't run assembler code, but machine code

Comment: i know, i meant like assembling it all to machine code the cpu emulator can read and process

Comment: thus would that ALSO require knowledge of the exact hardware the emulator is being ran on to call its hardware correctly, for example being ran with one type of graphics card vs a completely different type of graphics card, would i need to know how to call each type of graphics card

Comment: In practice, you'll better have some operating system on your emulated hardware (and details matter, so explain *what* OS you have on your emulated system; if you don't have any, give enough details about what graphics card is emulated)